# Low-resource, targeted and full-screen captures, why C#?

Tags: c#, c++, programming-languages, screen-capture, image-capture

I would like to be able to capture screenshots with C++ 'using a lot of compression', and/or more importantly 'uses very few system resources when capturing'.  I have been looking for concise, well-written examples, and I think I have found a few.  What I've found is that most of the examples are in C# and very few are in C++.  I'm sure there's a somewhat simple/common answer, and it's foolish to ask.  Why do people use C# instead of C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do people use C# instead of C++?

Because it's easier.

C++ gives you a lot of control over everything, and with that extra control comes extra responsibility and more work. If you just want to get something done quickly, using C# is usually sufficient.

Comment: Well, speed and downwards compatibility are what are important in my mind.  Good answer.